# Elixir run "clear" command using System on macOS

Tags: elixir

I have an elixir game of life implementation that prints a 'board' to STDOUT and I want to clear the screen before printing the next version of the board. I checked the [elixir documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#cmd/3) and I thought it would be as easy as calling `System.cmd("clear", [])` but this doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
iex(1)> System.cmd("clear", [])
{"\e[H\e[2J", 0}
```

It looks like some escaped characters are returned but I'm not sure what it means. **My question is why doesn't the `System.cmd("clear", [])` work? Or is my expectation that it should clear the screen wrong (and why)?**

Apparently iex has a convenience function `clear` to clear the screen which works in iex. I found out this helper method comes from the `IEx.Helpers` module and I can now run `IEx.Helpers.clear` and it clears the screen before printing another board.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like you mentioned the best way to clear the screen is to call the [clear helper](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.Helpers.html#clear/0):

```ex
IEx.Helpers.clear
```

---

To answer your other question, it's because the `System.cmd` command doesn't actually print anything to the console, it returns it (so the Elixir app can do something with it). The returned string (`\e[H\e[2J`) consists of the two ANSI escape codes that correspond to *"go home"* (`\e[H`) and *"clear"* (`\e[2J`).

You can test it yourself. Calling this would clear the screen (and return `:ok`):

```ex
IO.puts("\e[H\e[2J")
```

---

<sup>**Interesting Sidenote:** The reason why the IEx clear helper doesn't return `:ok`, is because of a [special function](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/7e0960b37ed0fc0d7cf721837359d0cd7a5b3099/lib/iex/lib/iex.ex#L754) that it calls at the end.</sup>

Comment: Redirecting the output back to console would also resolve the issue: `System.cmd("clear", [], into: IO.stream(:stdio, :line))`.